# Angular 6 form submitted property does not exist

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am build an angular application in which I used angular forms. It works well on angular 5 and also on angular 6. But when I go to deploy it by ng build -prod it gives the errors

[image]

Here is my code for logincomponent

```
<form class="md-float-material form-material" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="auth-box card">
        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="row m-b-20">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 class="text-center">User Login</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-primary">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-primary">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-primary">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block waves-effect waves-light text-center m-b-20">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="../../assets/images/Logo-small-bottom.png" alt="small-logo.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is TS Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertService, UserService } from '../_services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'login.component.html' })
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    returnUrl: string;
    selectedValue: 'observer';

    constructor(
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public route: ActivatedRoute,
        public router: Router,
        public userService: UserService,
        public alertService: AlertService) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });

        this.userService.logout();

        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    public onSubmit() {

        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }


        this.userService.login(this.loginForm.value)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.alertService.success('User Authenticated', true);
                },
                error => this.alertService.error(error, false)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems pretty spot on. You’re using ‘submitted’ in the template, I do not see it in the component?

Comment: @MikeOne it works on ng serve and give these errors on ng build --prod only

Comment: That hapoens. The prod builds are a lot more strict..

Answer (score 1):

This error is a result of AoT(Ahead of Time) compilation.

The reason why these errors don't show up while running "ng serve" is because *ng serve* performs JiT(Just in Time) compilation.

In AoT compilation, you have to have each and every methods/variables declared along with many other things.

Once you define the missing variables (like submitted on the LoginComponent) on your ts, those errors will go away.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, I would create an instance of FormControl in our class. For e.g.   loginForm = new FormControl();

Here is a good explanation of your problem:
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-formcontrol-example